# Magento Bulk product add to cart

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am facing problem with adding bulk products, I need like

I have product which sold with this conditions

2 Pack, 9.50 oz:  $6.78  (3.39/Unit)

6 Pack, 9.50 oz: $19.32 (3.22/Unit)

If I have select 2 Pack with QTY 2 then my cart will be

2 pack (6.78) * 2 (Qty) = 13.56

same way i will select

6 pack (19.22) * 2 (Qty) = 115.32

I need result like this.